# Is there a direct train from Brussels Airport to Antwerpen-Centraal?

Tags: trains, belgium, brussels, bru, antwerp

I need to get from Brussels Airport to Antwerpen-Centraal. I used http://www.thetrainline-europe.com/ which found me some direct trains, but when I click through to book with http://uk.voyages-sncf.com, all the trains are listed as stopping at Antwerpen-Berchem, which is a 30m walk from where I need to be. When I change the destination, the page gives an error.

Do I need to get two tickets to make that journey? Is there a direct train, or will I need to change at Antwerpen-Berchem?

Comment: As a side note there is also bus shuttle from the airport to Antwerpen-centraal (http://www.airportexpress.be)

Comment: I don't think there are many trains that go to Antwerpen-Berchem that don't stop in Antwerpen-Centraal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are direct trains but I would not trust voyages-sncf.com to book train journeys entirely outside France (or for anything else actually). [The official site from the Belgian State Railways](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/Splash.aspx) will show you all the trains and should allow you to buy a ticket online.

Another option to book the tickets would be [loco2](https://loco2.com) (I find the site nicer and easier to use than either SNCF or NMBS/SNCB but they only offer postal tickets for this journey so that's not very convenient).

Finally, you can buy a ticket on the day of travel, at the airport. Apart from international services (especially Thalys) and unlike in France, Germany or the UK, there is no advance booking discounts or seat reservations on trains in Belgium so little downside to buying the tickets at the last minute, except the need to plan some time for it. Besides, your train is little more than a suburban train, Belgium is quite small and Antwerpen is a bit over 30 min away from the airport.

Note that, depending on the site/language, the airport station is also called “Bruxelles Nat. Aéroport” or “Brussel Nationaal Luchthaven”.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to ask if tickets were flexible if my flight was delayed for any reason, but I think buying tickets on the day will be the easiest to plan for.

Comment: FYI, anyone else wondering the same thing - I bought tickets on the day, like this suggested. It was easy, simple and cheap with very obvious ticket machines in the airport arrivals. Finding the train platform was also very straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually an express bus I've used on several occasions.

http://www.airportexpress.be/page?pge=4&ssn=&lng=2

It takes a bit less than an hour and arrives at the central station in Antwerp and costs 10.00 EUR.